# react-router transitionTo: Invariant Violation: Missing "splat" parameter for path

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am using react-router with react.

I need to use query strings in my url like this:

```
let url = '/some/path/legal?id=2&name=QA_3%206*6*6';
this.context.router.transitionTo(url);
```

However, it does not do the redirect and throws an error:

```
Unhandled promise rejection Error: Invariant Violation: Missing "splat"  parameter for path "/some/path/legal?id=2&name=QA_3%206*6*6"
```

Seems that the splat (*) is not allowed in the query strings?

Comment: Which version of React-router you used ?

Comment: I'm using react-router@0.13.3. So, this might be the problem?

Comment: can you please post the code here because as per my knowledge you have to pass the routername in .transitionTo method like transitionTo('robots-edit', {id: 5})

Comment: Thank you, Dhaval Patel. Indeed I should use routername instead of a direct URL path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used this old version of react-router, but it looks like the signature is:

`routeName (string), params (object), query (unused)`

So try:

```
this.transitionTo('/some/path/legal', { id: 2, name: 'QA_3%206*6*6' });
```

I would have thought it'd be a `query` <s>[but it seems that is unused](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/issues/1148)</s>.

Edit, OP tested and seems it's used, so:

```
this.transitionTo('/some/path/legal', null, { id: 2, name: 'QA_3%206*6*6' });
```

Perhaps think about update to at least v1, which doesn't use `transitionTo` anymore. See https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/upgrade-guides/v1.0.0.md#navigation-mixin.

Comment: Thank you for your tips. It works if the code goes like this: `this.transitionTo('/some/path/legal', null, { id: 2, name: 'QA_3%206*6*6' });`

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was just a case of explicitly setting the `splat` parameter when transitioning to the new route:

```
router.transitionTo('help', {splat: 'content'});
```

given my route was:

```
<Route path="help/*" handler={HelpPage}/>
```